# How to write this equation in Matlab?

Tags: distribution, gaussian

x(t)=

Σ
    α<sub>i</sub>x<sub>t-i</sub>+ß+V<sub>t</sub>

​where V<sub>t</sub> ~ N(0,σ<sup>2</sup>)

With zero mean and σ<sup>2</sup> variance.

How to write this code in Matlab?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not enough has been done by the user. Looks like a homework.

Comment: The equation that comes to mind is `CH = EAT(ING)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for-loop in a script

```
endsum = 0;
for i= 1:p
    endsum = endsum + (alpha(i) [...and your equation here..]);
end
```